# Selecting cells from range object

Tags: excel, vba

```
Function test()
Dim rnge As Range
Set rnge = Range("sheet1!$B$2:$B$3")
For i = 1 To rnge.Count
rnge.Cells(i, rnge.Column).Select
Next i
End Function
```

It's selecting the C2 and C3 cells.

Why its selecting wrong range cells? 
What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I'm a little rusty but I think your only real issue was the column offset with this line of code:

```
   rnge.Cells(i, rnge.Column).Select
```

which should have been just:

```
   rnge.Cells(i).Select
```

With just one argument you can effectively iterate through every cell, first every column in the first row, then every column in the next row and so on. And no this index is definately not zero based. In .Net probably but in VBA zero based indexes are rarer.

I tend to use the altnerative For Each iterator:

```
   For Each cell In rnge.Cells
     ...
   Next cell
```

I think the second argument is a column offset (in your case value 2), but because your selection is only one column wide, it just addresses the cells outside the selection. The two value argument is itended for the x,y style addressing and so just produces this quirk. Remember the x,y is based on 1,1 being the left top most cell of your range, not the sheet.

The rest of this is just speculation of your intent.

Your code is going to select each cell in turn.

If you intend to just select all cells then:

```
  Range("sheet1!$B$2:$C$3").Select
```

will probably do it.

Alternatively if you only want to select certains cells, say based on the state of the cell, then you will need to union the cells together in another range, e.g.:

```
Dim selectionRange As Range
For Each cell In rnge.Cells
    If selectionRange Is Nothing Then
        Set selectionRange = cell
    Else
        Set selectionRange = Union(cell, selectionRange)
    End If
Next cell
If Not selectionRange Is Nothing Then
    selectionRange.Select
End If
```

Also note, that if Sheet1 is not the active worksheet then I think any attempt to select a cell on that sheet will cause an error.

Anyway I'm probably getting way of topic now so I'll leave it there.

Comment: Your solution worked and you have explained it very well, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this `"sheet1!$B$2:$B$3"` is invalid argument for `Range`. You should use it like this: `Sheets("sheet1").Range("B2:B3")`, i.e. first part (before dot) is sheet reference, then we specify range of cells to use.

Now, `rnge.Count` is equal to 2, so it will loop from `1 To 2` (note that `rnge.Column` is equal to 2) selecting respectively: `Cells(1, 2)` and `Cells(2, 2)` respectively to first cell of a `rnge`, which is B2, so it will select C2 and C3.

Why is it selecting respectively to `rnge`? Because you used `rnge.Cells(...)`, which does exactly that!

Comment: Actually this syntax works for me in Excel 2013. But it does seem to come up with C2 to C3. Very interesting.

Comment: In Excel 2016 it gives me error... strange. But except that, everything else stays true.

Comment: The range syntax is indeed perfectly valid as long as you have a sheet called Sheet1 and your code is not in the code module of a different sheet.

Comment: I think "sheet1!$B$2:$B$3"  cannot be an invalid argument  in case you get a range from a user selection using "RefEdit."

Answer (score -1):

Your Counter i for loop is Zero based! you should use:

```
For i = 0 To rnge.Count - 1
```

Oh and you should also define your variable:
`Dim i as integer`